# How to update a specific row and pass parameter using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

I am dynamically displaying table content by using json response. Here is my code for displaying row values

```
var rows = '';
for(var i=0; i<response.response.length; i++)
{
     rows += '<tr><td class="country">' + response.response[i].country 
          + '</td><td class="state">' + response.response[i].state 
          + '</td><td class="city">' + response.response[i].city 
          + '</td><td class="citizen_from">' + response.response[i].citizen_from 
          + '</td><td class="citizen_to">' + response.response[i].citizen_to 
          + '</td><th><a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Edit</a></th></tr>';
}

document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML += rows;
```

And the Output on html page is this:

Country     State   City    Citizenship From    Citizenship To

India   aa  xx  2014-02-12  2014-02-07        Edit

bbb bb        yy    2014-02-04  2014-02-10      Edit

yf  ctc     cg  2014-02-18  2014-02-25  Edit

Suppose I want to edit and update second row, What code I should write in Ajax to take second rows parameter only.
Any help will be appreciated 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: javascript only?  or are/can you use jquery?

Comment: If you have solution in jquery then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

ONLY DOING EXACTLY WHAT YOU REQUESTED:

Use an ajax callback:

```
var fAjaxCallback = function (data) {
    // build your replacement row, or whatever
    var sNewRow = '<tr>...</tr>';
    // update row 2 (index 1)
    document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr')[1].outerHTML = sNewRow;
};

// then pass that function definition into your ajax call
```